# How to enable adjusting of iFrame size manually in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two iframes used in a popup. In IE I am able to stretch the 1st frame manually, but its not possible in Firefox. How can I make this work?

Code of the 1st iFrame (which I need to be able to stretch manually):

```
<iframe name="iframeContent" id="iframeContent" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"
        style="width:100%;height:100%;border-right:0px;border-top:0px;border-left:5px solid #cccccc;border-bottom:5px solid #cccccc;"
        src="help.html" />
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the parent of the iframe? The fact that it works in IE, but not Firefox, means your markup is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply Rob.<frameset rows="84,*" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" onload="myOnLoad();">
    <frame name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="emHelp.html"/>
    <frameset cols="40%,605" frameborder="1" framespacing="2" border="0" bordercolor="#cccccc" onload="myOnLoad();">
      <frame name="frameDirectory" id="frameDirectory" frameborder="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no" src="blank.html"/>
   
   inside this frame to be resized comes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting the iframe to a height of 100% but what quantity is that? 100% of what? It's always the parent of the element so the iframe's parent is the body which is set to 100% but what value is that?

The parent of the body is `html` so what is html set to? And therein is the issue. Html's parent is the viewport and setting html's height to 100% will give you an actual dimension value of the height of the viewport which will cascade down to the iframe and give you an actual dimension value.

For that matter, you could also set any of those parents to an actual value such as 200px.

Comment: Thanks for reply Rob.I m trying trying that.Please find this frameset code also<frameset rows="84,*" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0" onload="myOnLoad();"> <frame name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="emHelp.html"/> <frameset cols="40%,605" frameborder="1" framespacing="2" border="0" bordercolor="#cccccc" onload="myOnLoad();"> <frame name="frameDirectory" id="frameDirectory" frameborder="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no" src="blank.html"/> inside this frame to be resized comes

Comment: changing height value doesn't work. While searching many sources i m getting links to noresize attribute n frameborder="0" or "no". If u have any guidance..it l help me lot.Thanks